# Need to upgrade Windows XP to Windows 7 without losing data

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, updates

I have a desktop with Windows XP on it that I urgently need to get it updated to Windows 7. I have heard from a friend that you need to do a clean install. Or is there a upgrade option, losing any data is not an option what would you suggest I do perhaps if I updated to Vista then to 7 would that work?

Comment: If you do a clean install you will without a shadow of a doubt lose your data.  Just do an in-place upgrade to a licensed Windows Vista installation then an in-place upgrade to a Windows 7 licensed installation.  You should of course backup your personal files before you do anything If "losing any data is not an option" You should also read [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7#T1=tab06)

Answer (score 2):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

You can use the Windows Easy transfer to transfer files and settings. Software will have to be reinstalled though.

Comment: There is no excuse for no backup of data anymore, however. If the OP is so concerned about not losing data then even doing an "in-place" upgrade could result in catastrophic failure and data loss. It is the most important thing to do with a computer!